# My android app is not rotating. Where could the problem be?

Tags: java, android, android-orientation

Rotating can't seem to work in my app. I can't find where the problem is. If someone could help with that. At first it was working, but then I don't what changed in the code that made it stop rotating.If any classes other than the android manifest may contain the error please let me know in order to upload it Thank you.

Here is my AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.how">
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the "MyLocation" functionality.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.HOW">
    
    <activity android:name=".UploadID"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.UploadID"/>
    <activity android:name=".Register" />
    <activity android:name=".Login" />
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    <provider
        android:authorities="com.example.how.fileprovider"
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">

        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>


    </provider>

    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Remove android:screenOrientation="portrait" from android:name=".UploadID" it will be fixed.

Comment: @AquibAli but this is only for the UploadID activity, and not for the whole app

Comment: @AquibAli didn't work, I tried it

Comment: make sure in android device auto-rotate is on .

Answer (score 0):

To use the user specified rotation, use this code:

`activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER);`

Comment: where should I add this line?

Comment: In the activity that you would like to rotate.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove **android:screenOrientation="portrait"** in the manifest file otherwise add sensor instead of portrait.

Or in the whole Activity add **android:screenOrientation="sensor"** in the manifest